# Is twitter streaming api exactly 1 percent of the whole streaming?

Tags: api, twitter, streaming, tweepy

I am using tweepy package to crawl tweets. Just wonder whether the tweets I get are exactly 1 percent of all the tweets in the streaming?
Anybody know that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly if they didn't change the way they sample from the time this blog post was written: http://blog.falcondai.com/2013/06/666-and-how-twitter-samples-tweets-in.html

According to the article they send the tweets that where published between the 657th and the 666th millisecond. So it's not exactly 1% but a good approximation.